# MongoDB installation on CentOS

Tags: mongodb, centos, installation, centos6, yum

I tried installing MongoDB on a minimal CentOS 6.8 image.

My shell script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

MONGODB_V="2.6.1"

cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo <<EOL
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOL

sudo yum install "mongodb-org-$MONGODB_V"
sudo yum install "mongodb-org-server-$MONGODB_V"
sudo yum install "mongodb-org-shell-$MONGODB_V"
sudo yum install "mongodb-org-mongos-$MONGODB_V"
sudo yum install "mongodb-org-tools-$MONGODB_V"

mkdir -p /data/db
```

Everything works well on the installation side but I can't seem to start MongoDB.

I tried:

```
sudo service mongod start # mongod: unrecognized service
/opt/mongo/bin/mongod
/usr/local/bin/mongod
```

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made a stupid mistake:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo
```

should've been:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
```

The repository changed since the `10gen` company changed their name to `Mongodb inc.`.